# Android: Update an Image label in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, textview, imageview

I have around 8 images in a Gridview and each image has a text assigned with a default value.  On loading the app, I would like to update each image's text with an updated value that I fetch from the database/file.

I have stored values in database like image_nameX, value.

Default value for each image is set using "android:text="0".

My question is, 
1. how do I update the label of a particular image in a Gridview?
2. Is there a way to identify image id and set text (update) to that particular Id?

Thanks
Aravind

Comment: I think you should use an Adapter to bind your data from database to your GridView. In that case, you images will use the information you have stored in your database

Answer (score 0):

Update your data model to what you want displayed then simply call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. This will let the GridView know that the data has changed and it will update the views.

Comment: But how do I identify the image Id for update? Lets say I have two images with default text having value "0" and I want to update Image1's text value with "2" and Image2's text value with "3", for instance. 

txtView.setText(..) doesn't seem to be taking ImageId as an argument for update. Like txtView.setText(imageId, updateValue). 

Is it possible to do with txtView.setText(..) or any alternate way?

Comment: You can't get the text from an ImageView. Is there reason you're giving it a text? Perhaps adding it to tag would be an alternative. You can do setTag/getTag on the ImageView

Comment: If you're trying to display text just use a TextView

Comment: Can post your layout xml file?

Comment: The application is an voting application. An image with two buttons "Yes" and "No" with a default value of "0" for both "Yes" and "No" . 

An incremented value will be stored onto a database like, ImageName->Yes(no. of times clicked)/ No (no. of times clicked)

On re-loading the app, each image's Yes and No button should be updated with the no. of times clicked. To set and show the updated value I'm using TextView.